# Hiding nested options in li menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i cant figure out how to hide the nested options on my menu. id like to hide everything under "s01" and "s02".

when you click scream queens, the menu expands to show everything. id like it to only show "s01" or "s02" then when a user clicks on "s01" for example. only those links expand.

im fairly new to jquery and so far like it.

any help would be helpfull, thank you

**[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/2ajq59re/5/)**

```js
$('.items ul').hide();

$('.sub_items').click(function () {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.navigation
{
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.items
{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.entries
{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation">
<li class="sub_navigation">TV Series
    <ul class="items">
        <li class="sub_items">Scream Queens
            <ul class="items">
                <li class="sub_items">S01
                    <ul class="entries">
                        <li class="sub_entries">Preview</li>
                        <li class="sub_entries">Inside Look</li>
                        <li class="sub_entries">Preview #02</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sub_items">S02
                    <ul class="entries">
                        <li class="sub_entries">Preview</li>
                        <li class="sub_entries">Inside Look</li>
                        <li class="sub_entries">Preview #02</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub_items">Shannara Chronicles, The
            <ul class="entries">
                <li class="sub_entries">S01</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub_items">Walking Dead, The
            <ul class="entries">
                <li class="sub_entries">S06</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that everything that is contained within your `li` is part of that `li`, even if it is a `ul`. So if you click on a `ul` that is within a `li`, the click event for both fires.

I added a `label` around all your texts to have something other than the li to address:

```
<li class="sub_items"><label>Scream Queens</label>
```

Then adjusted the jquery as follows:

```
$('.items ul').hide();

$('.sub_items > label').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(' > ul').slideToggle();
});
```

So I am only listening to the click event of the `label`, then get the parent element, then toggle only the directly descending `ul` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Find an updated JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/2ajq59re/13/.

```
$('.items ul').hide();

$('.sub_items > a').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.items').stop().slideToggle();
});

$('.sub_items2').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.entries').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

The Your sub-items need to have a separate identifier from the parent class and a separate click function (I have just renamed them as .sub_items2 for this example, use what you like. I have also put the click function onto an anchor tag which I have wrapped around Scream Queens (the parent). This stops the first click function you had from closing everything when clicking the children and not just the "title".

Following the same format, your other items would work with the same two click functions. .find() has been changed to .next() as the click function is no longer targeting the parent but a sibling.

Also I have added .stop(). You will find this very useful with slideToggle(). It stops a "queue" (i.e. after multiple clicks it doesnt carry out the remaining actions, on a click halfway through, it stops itself and goes the other way).

Happy Coding! :-)

Comment: thk you for your help. over the past couple of days, ive gotten things to flow right. one more question. how would i have a section showing instead of hidden? for example if i wanted to show a new product but the rest of the list would remain collapsed.. maybe i wanted to show coffee cups > spiritual > ouija > ouija board.

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` finds all children, You should use `>` - direct child operator `.find(' > ul')`. However now click event is bubbling and triggering click on parent, to prevent that You should pass `event` to `click` event, and stop bubbling.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ajq59re/14/)

```
$('.items ul').hide();

$('.sub_items').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```